# Bottles of Beer - what is this: var bottlesDiv = document

Tags: javascript, dom, getelementbyid

I've followed a very basic Bottles of Beer tutorial (different than the ones mentioned already on this site) and I do not understand what this portion is doing:

```
var bottlesDiv = document.
```

Full code here (and it does work as expected):

```js
 

var bottles = 99;
var lyrics = "";
while (bottles > 0) {
lyrics = lyrics + bottles + " bottles of beer on the wall <br>";
lyrics = lyrics + bottles + " bottles of beer <br>";
lyrics = lyrics + "Take one down, pass it around, <br>";
bottles = bottles - 1;
if (bottles > 0) {
 lyrics = lyrics + bottles + " bottles of beer on the wall <br><br>";
} else {
 lyrics = lyrics + "No more bottles of beer on the wall. <br>";
}
}
var bottlesDiv = document.
getElementById("bottles");
bottlesDiv.innerHTML = lyrics;
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <title>99 Bottles of Beer</title>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
 <h1>99 Bottles of Beer </h1>
 <div id="bottles"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That line is only half a statement. The code is easier to understand if you join it with the following line `var bottlesDiv = document.getElementById("bottles");`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is actually a multi-line JavaScript statement:

```
// define the bottlesDiv variable and assign to it
var bottlesDiv = document // start at window.document which is the root of the page
  .getElementById('bottles'); // find the element in document with id = bottles
```

It definitely makes more sense when written as:

```
var bottlesDiv =
  document.getElementById('bottles');
```

Comment: Thank you, that's the problem with using tutorials from magazines I think, they ran out of room in the column.

Answer (score 0):

`var bottlesDiv = document.getElementById("bottles");`

It is merely a case of incorrect formatting. bottlesDiv is the variable holding the element with the id of bottles.

`getElementById()` is a Javascript selector function.

Comment: It's not necessarily "incorrect." It's certainly a bit confusing on first glance if you're not used to it.

Answer (score 0):

Its not

var bottlesDiv = document.

Its

var bottlesDiv = document.getElementById("bottles");

It reads until the semi colon.

Comment: Sorry to be pedantic, but it doesn't read until the semicolon. JavaScript has automatic semicolon insertion. It reads until it finds a valid expression. `document.` is not, by itself, a valid expression so it's safe to split it up over multiple lines. Something like `return true` can't be split up because `return` by itself *is* a valid expression.

Comment: I should correct myself by saying both expressions (before and after the split) need to be valid for an automatic semicolon insertion to happen. So you can split it up like `document.` or like `.getElementById("bottles")`. Both would work because a dot can neither begin nor end an expression.